# Region keyword in Functions

Tags: c#, vb.net

I generally use to organize codes below lines;

```
#Region "Comments.."
#End Region
```

But when I want to use it in the Function, it gives error ("..are not valid within...").
Are there any keyword to make this in the Function or there aren't?

Below gives error.

```
Public Function Mail() As Boolean
        #Region "Error"
        #End Region
End Function
```

For vb.net, but same problem continues in c#.

Comment: You need to provide an example of where it doesn't work, as well as the full error message.

Comment: can you show how you use it and the full error details? C# or VB anyway?

Comment: _"But when I want to use it in the Function"_ What do you mean exactly? Code and full error please.

Comment: If you feel that you need regions inside a method you should consider to refactor that method.

Comment: The same problem does not happen in C#. It's perfectly legal to place regions in methods. However, to mirror others, if you feel you need to do this something is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w96cy299.aspx):

> The #Region block must be declared at a class, module, or namespace level. A collapsible region can include one or more procedures, but it cannot begin or end inside of a procedure.

So, no, there is no way to do that.

Comment: No, there isn't. Consider doing what Mikael said in his comment, refactor and extract the code into individual methods.

Comment: @ToUpper "I only asked are there any method like #Region to use in the Function" indeed; and Lasse only answered (citing a source from the documentation); the answer is simply "no".

Answer (score 3):

as  Marc Gravell said its legal to put #regions inside functions.
refer following example in c#

```
private void showMessags(int ID)
    {  
         #region " Display Message "
         if (ID == 1)
             {          
                 lblMessage.Text = "Hi";
             }
         else if (ID == 2)
             {
                 lblMessage.Text = "Hello";
             }
         #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Errrr... If you need to put regions in your methods, you're doing it wrong. They're not supposed to be pages long!